# Why is my third Twitter request always timing out?

Tags: c#, api, twitter, timeout, dotnetopenauth

This is getting annoying. I have an application that is supposed to post status information on Twitter. It is written in C# and uses [DotNetOpenAuth](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/) for authentication.

I make a status update with the following code:

```
var the_request = m_consumer.PrepareAuthorizedRequest(status_endpoint,
                                                      m_access_token);
the_request.GetResponse();
```

The first two status updates always execute flawlessly and virtually immediately.

Then the third one times out. I get an exception of type `System.Net.WebException` thrown.

No matter what I do, it's *always* the third request that times out. Any subsequent requests time out.

What is going on here?

Comment: How fast are you making the requests?

Comment: @Martin: Hmmm... I guess as fast as I can ship them off.

Comment: I know there is a rate limit, but I didn't think it would come into effect here. If so, how come subsequent retries fail too then? I wait 30 seconds between calls.

Comment: Is there any more detail in the `WebException`?

Comment: @Dan: No, there is not. I went through everything in the exception with the debugger, and 'Timeout' was the only useful thing I pulled from it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume **the_request** is a HttpWebRequest. It leads to timeout if the streams are not closed properly. Make sure to close both of your request & response stream after each request

```
the_request.GetResponse();
the_request.close()
```

and

```
   var resp = the_request.GetResponse();
   //your logic to handle to response
   resp.close()
```

Comment: That's it! That was the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Each twitter API has a rate limit.

I see the default rate is 150 requests per hour.
Depends how they implement the throttling but that's about 2.5 requests a minute.

Have you tried waiting 30 seconds between each request.

Comment: @George Edison: At that point you may have already breached the throttling so they are holding out. Try putting a 30 second pause between each request and see if you get 3 in a row. If that works reduce the period until you hit the sweet spot.